# Find the ID of a common parent element

Tags: jquery

Using this HTML as an example to illustrate what I would like to achieve when the second .multi element in the second group is clicked :

```
<div id="someID1">
    <div id="someID2">
        <div class="multi">hello world</div>
        <div>
            <div class="multi">hello world</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="multi">hello world</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="someID3">
        <div class="multi">hello world</div>
        <div>
            <div class="multi">I am the one clicked in this example</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="multi">hello world</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Create a jQuery selector that can taget all three and only the three instances of .multi contained inside #someID3.
I have no control over the class or ID of #someID3.
The structure of the contents inside #someID3 could be anything. All that is known is that it will contain at least one instance of .multi element. We know this because it was clicked.
But we want to target all instances of .multi inside #someID3 inside the click event.
For illustration, lets say we just want to change their background colour.

```
$(".multi").click(function(){
    // find the common parent ID, in this case #someID3..?
    var theCommonParentID = ??
    // so we can then do..
    $(theCommonParentID + " .multi").css("background","#ff0000");
})
```

I do not believe this is valid jQuery, but it's kind of what i think i need to do :

```
$(".multi").click(function(){
    var theCommonParentID;
    $(this).parents().each(function({
        if ($(".mutli", this).length > 0){
            theCommonParentID = $(this).attr("id");
        }else{
            $(theCommonParentID + " .multi").css("background","#ff0000");
            return
        }
    }));
})
```

Comment: so what is the defining attribute of the common parent exactly?  as i understand there is no attribute of parent which is specific to containers of multi elements

Comment: The only thing that is known is that there will be an element that contains the .multi element, and possibly multiple multi elements. I I could do something like this in the click event I could iterate outward until there is no .multi inside, then i'd know the parent element i'm looking for. I have put my example at the end of edited question above.

Comment: no this would not work, as every parent of the needed parent would  in fact contain the multi elements, this is the dom

Comment: unless you search for the minimum such parent, but in that case only the multi children should be considereed and not all possible multi descendats because in such a case you will eventually arrive at the body element

Comment: It's a no go, without a known class on the common parent I am trying to find ain't it..! This is what I have been discussing with the developer of the application I am making the add ons for, but he is reluctant to add a class to what the grouping wrapper that will always be present, saying children should not know anything about parents. Ah well cheers anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that it is the first ancestor with an id attribute so

```
$(".multi").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div[id]').find('.multi').css("background","#ff0000");
})
```

Comment: But as said this inner structure of #someID3 is just for illustration, it could in fact be a bunch of any elements with id's and classes. I think the only approach is to iterate through each parent and on each iteration test for the presence of a .multi inside. As soon as there is no .multi inside, we know we just went one iteration to far.. Problem is I don't know a way to do that..?